# Descrição do Campo EF Core

Tags: c#, postgresql, database-first

Bom Dia
Supondo que tenho um campo 'Descricao' no banco, como faço via Fluent API para no retorno vir "Descrição" (pra poder aparecer escrito corretamente em tela )

Comment: ideal seria algumas informações a mais... onde vocÊ está colocando isso... mas deve ser usando a dataannotation [DisplayName("Descrição")] em cima da declaração da propriedade